# Parameterize chained calls to a utility program in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I have a black box UNIX program used in a Bash shell that reads columns of data from stdin, processes them (applying a smoothing effect) then outputs to stdout. I use it by UNIX pipes, like

```
generate | smooth | plot
```

For more smoothing, I can repeat the smooth, so it'd be invoked from the Bash command line as

```
generate | smooth | smooth | plot
```

or even

```
generate | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | plot
```

This is getting unweildy. I would like to make a Bash wrapper to be able to pipe  into `smooth` and feed its output right back into a new instance of `smooth` an arbitrary number of times, something like

```
generate | newsmooth 5 | plot
```

instead of

```
generate | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | plot
```

My first attempt was a Bash script that generated temp files in the current directory and deleted them, but that turned ugly when I wasn't in a directory with write access, and also left garbage files when interrupted.

There are no arguments to the `smooth` program.

Is there a more elegant way to "wrap" such a program to parameterize the number of calls?

Comment: I hope your example is a forced case for the sake of the question and not an actual need

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could wrap it in a recursive function:

```
smooth() {
  if [[ $1 -gt 1 ]]; then # add another call to function
    command smooth | smooth $(($1 - 1)) 
  else
    command smooth # no further 
  fi
}
```

You would use this as

```
generate | smooth 5 | plot
```

which would be equivalent to

```
generate | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | smooth | plot
```

Comment: This is perfect, behaves exactly as needed. And now I learned about the bash "command" keyword.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the same approach I use in [How do I code an arbitrarily long chain of pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212663/how-do-i-code-an-arbitrarily-long-chain-of-pipes) -- and, long before that, in [handling long edit lists in xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898939/handling-long-edit-lists-in-xmlstarlet).

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford to type as many commas as the amount of `smooth` commands you want, you might take advantage of the shell's comma-separated Brace Expansion.

**TL; DR**

The whole command-line for your sample case would be:

```bash
generate | eval 'smooth |'{,,,,} plot
```

Note:

- add or remove commas if you want more or fewer repetitions of `smooth |`
- there's no `|` before `plot` because that's included in the last `smooth |` string produced by the Brace Expansion
- you can also provide arguments to `smooth`, as long as you can include them correctly within the quoted fixed part that precedes the open brace; in any case remember that you'd be providing them to *all* repetitions of the command

**How it works**

Comma-separated Brace Expansion allows you to dynamically produce strings, each made of a specified fixed part plus the specified variable parts. It produces as many strings as there are variable parts indicated, like `a{b,c,d}` produces `ab ac ad`.

The little trick here is that if you rather make a list of *empty* variable parts, i.e. with only commas inside the braces, the Brace Expansion will just produce copies of the fixed part only. For instance:

```bash
smooth{,,,,}
```

will produce:

```
smooth smooth smooth smooth smooth
```

Note that **4** commas produces 5 `smooth` strings. That's just how this Brace Expansion works: it produces strings as many commas plus one.

Of course in your case you need also a `|` separating each `smooth`, so just add it in the fixed part but take care to quote it properly to have the shell *not* interpret it at once. That is:

```bash
'smooth|'{,,,,}
```

will produce:

```
'smooth|' 'smooth|' 'smooth|' 'smooth|' 'smooth|'
```

Take care of always placing the fixed part *immediately* adjacent to the open brace, i.e. no spaces between the `'` and the `{`.

*(Note also that to form the fixed part you may also use double-quotes instead of single-quotes, if you need to expand shell variables in the fixed part. Just take care of the extra escaping that are required when some shell's special characters occur inside a double-quoted string).*

At this point you need an `eval` applied to that string in order to make the shell finally interpret it as the pipelined command it is supposed to be.

Thus, to sum it all, the whole command-line for your sample case would be:

```bash
generate | eval 'smooth |'{,,,,} plot
```

Comment: There are significant security concerns if this is used in places where the call is parameterized. See my answer on [Recursive bash function vs iterative “eval” string building: Which performs better?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452558/14122) over on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I fully agree with your concerns about the implied risks on using `eval` when one provides untrusted, non-sanitized, strings for it to evaluate, that is when used with variables that may carry "unknown" content like the case you linked. On the other hand, `eval` can also be very handy for quick "plumbing" of commands, especially when used at the prompt, like the case at hand seems to be, where `eval`'s input would only be a literal string typed manually by the user in person

Comment: As already seen elsewhere, you can always replace `eval str` with something pretentious & stupid like `. /dev/stdin <<<str`. Not  only will this make an impression on fools, it will also keep @CharlesDuffy off your back ;-)

Comment: @pizdelect, you might read LL3's prior comment carefully -- it's balanced, nuanced and wise. (Indeed, my own initial comment had nuances you seem to be ignoring; "if used in cases where the call is parameterized" is a critical distinction: LL3's instance *isn't* parameterized, making it safe).